# How to calculate the accuracy by hand for knn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, knn

I am currently learning some machine learning and I know how to calculate the euclidean distance between different data points; however, I was wondering if anyone knows how to calculate the accuracy by hand in order to see which k-value is the best as the choice of "k"?

I know how to implement basic python classes to calculate the accuracy for me, but want to learn how to do it by hand as well. I tried googling it, but they all just show python implementations.

For instance, let's pretend you only have 8 data points, 4 red and 4 orange; I pick for instance k = 3 and get 2 red and 1 orange (so the new data point is classified as red). Now I want to calculate the accuracy of this K value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accuracy is:

> Accuracy = (TP + TN)/(TP + TN + FP + FN)

According to [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) in binary classification, which your problem is. You could either define "red" as positive, or "orange" as positive. But that doesn't really matter here. Say we define "red" to be the positive class.

Then in the context of the formula above:

- TN: means true negatives (the points that were classified as orange and really are orange)
- TP: means true positives (the points that were classified as red and really are red)
- FN: means false negatives (the points that were classified as orange, but in fact are red)
- FP: means false positives (the points that were classified as red, but in fact are orange)

So you can even make the formula simpler, because `TN+TP+FN+FP` is the number of points in total and `TP+TN` is the number of correctly classified points (which KNN predicts correctly).

Comment: So if my case is K=3 that means I have a total of 3 values (excluding the newly added data point that was classified as "red"), whereas 2 values is positive and 1 value is negative. I take the number of points in total (which is 3 then I assume?) and... there I was lost :P not sure how to know the "number of correctly classified points" from my example for instance?

Comment: No, the choice of k has no direct influence. It only influences the prediction. The accuracy is only calculated by comparing the predictions with the true values. you need "labelled" data to calculate it. In your example, you would calculate the 3 closest points to each point of a set of points (the validation set) and for each point predict the mayority vote. Then you calculate number_correctly_predicted/number_total.

Comment: So, let's say I have 3 points around my "chosen" point that is yet to be classified by the majority vote. I calculate this point first, and then go around the other 3 points that is closest to that one and see their 3 closest relatives and decide the majority vote for all. Then I simply compare this to the true values somehow?

Comment: You need the accuracy to test the quality of your model. You do that by chosing a point that was not in the training set, then you search it's three closest neighbour, decide by mayority vote, what class it should be in and then count this point as correctly (TP or TN) / incorrectly classified (FN or FP) and do that for all points in the test set, then you calculate (num correctly classified) / number of points in the training set.

Comment: Well, I currently have this: 
https://imgur.com/a/F5ghrXb
I can clearly see the majority vote will make it "black". I guess this would make it TP? The thing I don't get is when you say "do it for all points in the test set", my test set is those 3 values right? (or 4 if you count the new one). But should i calculate the closest neighbour for all 3 of the other points?

Comment: For example, how would you do do find out the accuracy for k = 3 in the image I sent a link to? The thing is, I can do the steps as far as to classify the new variable through a majority vote, but from there on (despite your description (I'm really not good at this)) I'm still a bit lost.

Comment: Yes, that point would be black. This is what your model would predict. But to test your model, you need to let it predict a point for which you know what the actual "color" is and only then can you decide whether it was correctly classified- Without labels, you can't tell if it is TP, TN, FP or FN and so also not check if your model is good in predicting your data or not.

Comment: Ah, I get it! Thank you!

Comment: If you like ML and want to get into it, I can really recommend this book for you (not quite cheap, but heavily loaded with infos): https://www.amazon.se/Hands-Machine-Learning-Scikit-Intelligent/dp/1492032646/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=hands+on+machine+learning&qid=1606989290&sr=8-1. Greetings to Uppsala. I have a kind of pen-friend there since about 15 years :-)